# during ondrag how to not display the X/stop sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm letting my client drag a certain div around the document. However I cannot disable the afterimage and the X sign, I don't want it to show anything extra.

The only way I found around this is:

```
  $(document).on('dragover', function(e){
     event.preventDefault();
  });
```

which would get rid of the X, but the after-image is still there, and it feel unnecessary to add an eventlistener for this.

I read other questions, but they all just want to get rid of the dragging event.

Any suggestion? please

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/3awoap5g/ it wont work properly on jsfiddle though because I'm using pageX n pageY

Comment: maybe a jsfiddle ?

Comment: updated, take a look

Comment: do you mean by the afterimage that there is a duplicate of the element when you are dragging?

Comment: yeah, but not talking about the one I created on purpose by ondrag and .css. I don't want the 'automatically' generated one. I dont want the X/forbidden sign either

Comment: i dont see any X signs in the fiddle ? where shall it be ?

Comment: I took a photo of it http://postimg.org/image/r13tl6kln/. So Im trying to get rid of that X and the afterimage that wasnt created by me